# Loading plain PHP class into Laravel 5.1 environment

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a plain PHP class written like this

```
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $error_messages = array(
        1 => 'blabla bla bla',
        2 => 'lorem ipsum...',
        3 => 'let\'s pray...'
    );
    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {

    }
    protected function initialize() {

    }
}
```

How do I load this into Laravel 5.1 environment and simply call the class like this

`$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();`

I understand that we have to use Facade but not really sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with calling the class like

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

If you want to resolve it using the dependancy injection (IOC) then you can bind the class in a service provider.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers#the-register-method

Comment: can you elaborate in details?